# Failure criteria for CFRP single plate bolted joint

Tags: aerospace-engineering, mechanical, machine-design, aircraft-design, composite

Which equation can be used to find failure based on ply orientation.
Tension,shear & bearing faliure to validate against fem analysis
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to familiarize with the "yield line theory" and stress concentration around bolt holes. I don't know what you mean of "equation can be used", as all three are potential failure modes to be investigated over the assumed failure areas with respect to the resulting stress, whether is tensile, shear, bending, or combined stresses.